# SSMS - Data load Option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have recently installed the newer version of SSMS on my system. But the option to load the excel file is grey out. I'm not able to load BULK Load

I tried to run DTSWizard.exe, even it doesn't give me the option to load the data from Excel sheet.

Please find the attachment

[image]

[image]

Here are my instances installed on this system

[image]

Comment: Options are enabled for me, but are you trying to use SSMS 18 against unsupported versions of SQL Server? I don't have any 2008 instances to try this on, but if you have to manage older versions like that, you might consider *also* running an older version of SSMS side-by-side.

Comment: @AaronBertrand 
Thank you for an update. I'm very new to DBA field and regarding the configuration and server instances on the SQL Express edition. 
Please find the screenshot of the my Control Panel -> Add or Remove Program ->

I have added the screenshot in original post

Comment: Have you checked that you have the right permissions to perform these tasks?

Comment: Yes, I checked my permission and it looks fine. I've added sysadmin aces to my account

Comment: @AvinashKumar, may this will help,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646025/sql-management-studio-task-import-data-is-greyed-out